# Click on html a text with JAVA

Tags: java, html, selenium, jsoup, htmlunit

I'm trying make a class that can click on A text/button in html. The page have user and password so I used JSOUP to parse the document using .data to insert user and password:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("url").data("user", user)
                .data("password", password)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                .timeout(3000).post();
```

At this point all was working OK. But now I have an button in html like this:

```
<a type="button" id="request" onclick="request(this)" class="lightButton"><i class="loading" style="display:none"><span class="ifont"></span></i>Request</a>
```

But I don't know how to click that text/button.

Somebody know how cand I make it? Thanks

Comment: Show your attempt with Selenium

Comment: @BillHileman I first thinked it was and element with ID, but is a text. I coludn't made the login post with selenium. The code for element that doesn't work was this:

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("url");
  
  try {
   
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   driver.findElement(By.id("request")).click();
   
  }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
  }

ALSO GAVE ME THIS ERROR: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\tests\\chromedriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("window-size=1024,768");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        driver.get("http://google.com/");

        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"gb_we\")[0].click()");
        }

    WebElement fName=driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
    fName.sendKeys("test@gmail.com");

    WebElement btnNext =driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext"));
    btnNext.click();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to adapt to my code, but you know how to post .data with user and password?
Like this method with JSUOP: Jsoup.connect("url").data("user",user).data("password", password)

Comment: thanks, It works, but now, there is some way to execute it without the gui interface?

Comment: add options.addArguments("headless");

Comment: That option doesn't work, it get timeout. Btw, i have this warning:    

org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFORMACIÓN: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`     
  it works in window mode, but in headless it have timeout after this line:
Detected dialect: OSS
||||||||||||||||||| -  - - - - 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
This line of your code is correct?